# Log of actions done in ranger?

Tags: ranger

Is it possible for `ranger` to record file/folder actions? I'm looking for a logging feature for every file/folder action done in `ranger`.

Answer (score 0):

As of now, [this](https://github.com/ranger/ranger/issues/1527) issue says it has not yet been implemented. It would seem that if you went ahead and added the necessary code, that would be received positively.

The changes you would have to make would be rather straightforward:

As in [line 1633 of `actions.py`](https://github.com/ranger/ranger/blob/master/ranger/core/actions.py#L1633),

```py
        self.notify("Deleting {fls}!".format(fls=", ".join(files)))
```

you add a `self.notify(…)` to all the actions (`rename`, `copy`…) that seem relevant.

Happy hacking!